# Where to sit and work for a couple of hours in Rome near Stazione Termini?

Tags: work, rome

I am going to Rome and I am arriving quite early. As will be waiting for some friends before heading to the location where we stay I am looking for a place, near Stazione Termini where I can quietly sit and work for a couple of hours.

Besides my computer I have some hand luggage.

**Where to sit and work for a couple of hours in Rome?**,

Comment: Where are you arriving? Rome is huge and it does make a difference if you're travelling by car, train or plane

Comment: @Noldor130884 I am arriving by plane but than heading to the city center.

Comment: Fiumicino or Ciampino? Can you go alone to the center, or do you have to wait in the airport or near it?

Comment: @Noldor130884 what does it change? I will head to the city center once I arrive. I can stay in ciampino as well if there are better places to work.

Comment: well first of all you need to consider the connection time. Places like "Feltrinelli" close at a certain hour. Secondly, Fiumicino is connected by train, while Ciampino is not. You can stop to a lot of train stations before Termini, while from Ciampino you'd have more restrictive options. Finally, Fiumicino has a couple of lounges, while Ciampino doesn't.

Comment: Rome is a huge city with dozens of locations that fit your requirements. Closing as too broad.

Comment: @JonathanReez made it more precise.

Comment: Unless Rome is in Spain now, it should be Stazione Termini.

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty of places. I'll name some here:

**[La Feltrinelli](http://www.lafeltrinelli.it/)**:

(my favorite), you can find big Feltrinelli stores with bars in most big Italian cities. Although there are generally few seats and if you are unlucky you might not be able to find an empty one.

> Location: Largo Argentina 5 (centre, well connected with buses and cabs, at a reasonable distance from metro station Spagna, line A)

and other locations (make sure to search for the ones that have a bar).

---

**[Circus](https://www.romeing.it/circus_roma/)**

> Location: Via della Vetrina 15 (centre, near piazza Navona, well connected with buses and cabs, at a reasonable distance from metro station Spagna, line A)

---

**[Arnold Coffee](http://www.arnoldcoffee.it/)**:

if you prefer American coffee try this one.

> Location: Via Giustiniani 15/b  (centre, near the Pantheon, well connected with buses and cabs, at a reasonable distance from metro station Spagna, line A)

---

**[Caffè Letterario](http://www.caffeletterarioroma.it/)**

> Location: Via Ostiense, 95 (near metro Piramide, line B, and railway station Roma Ostiense)

---

[**AntiCafé**](https://www.anticafe.eu/roma)

> Location: Via Veio, 4b (near metro San Giovanni, line A)

---

Find more [here](https://www.scattidigusto.it/2015/10/30/ristorante-roma-10-locali-studiare-lavorare/) and [here](https://www.romatips.it/wifi-gratuito-dove-studiare-roma/).

Comment: You are more or less implying that the OP is arriving in the center of Rome.

Comment: @Noldor130884 correct; that's what I assumed at least :)

Comment: I would be happy to upvote your answer, if you "linked" those places to the nearest train stations (e.g. Feltrinell - Termini, Caffè Letterario - Ostiense) and if you added a couple of infos on the airports (Fiumicino / Ciampino) ;)

Comment: @Noldor130884 sure, I will update with more places as soon as I find time :)